# Bypassing date picker on webpage, executing onclick function

Tags: html, excel, vba, internet-explorer, browser-automation

I want to convert an Excel report from our roster webapp into ics calendar events.

I would like, using VBA, to log in and export the roster by selecting the start and end dates.
The start and end date fields are changed by using the date picker (the boxes can't be typed into). I tried to change them by using `getElementbyId`.

EDIT: I haven't been able to figure out how to pass in a new date using Id. I would like to click the calendar icon to launch the datepicker but the button doesn't have an id, and using the getElementsbyTagName is proving a nightmare as there are so many entries, all without ids.
So I'm now trying to execute the code that happens with the onclick (toggleCalendarShow())

```
<TD vAlign=middle><IMG onclick=ctl00xContentPlaceHolder1xtxtstartdateClass.toggleCalendarShow() style="CURSOR: pointer" src="/WebResource.axd?d=isQhimlyp5Th1A7pbrVSPZZmakOc3oiCW_ZfNR9fV1S7PA1gESOWQyDsbZ8jC0DpnrCaO5u8n1xsrNzdQvzMJOpZADHN1t7AN4GTQ-viIM4F0-SAccLr5VyKvi3HXEYZ12VD3X7VI7eXCnCANJFULkTRI3M1&amp;t=633521043060000000"></TD>
```

I can execute the two functions in the Internet Explorer console, and it changes the date as I want, but it comes back with 'undefined'.
When I call it from VBA it comes up with error undefined and doesn't change the date.

```
'Select Show Hours
IE.document.GetElementById("ContentPlaceHolder1_Select_ShowHours").Checked = True

'Select Staff as "Me Only"
IE.document.GetElementById("ContentPlaceHolder1_Select_Staff").Value = "999"

ie.document.all.Item
Call ie.document.parentWindow.execScript("ct100xContentPlaceHolder1xtxtstartdateClass.toggleCalendarShow();", "JavaScript")
Call ie.document.parentWindow.execScript("ctl00xContentPlaceHolder1xtxtstartdateClass.selectDate ((15));", "JavaScript")

'Run Report
IE.document.GetElementById("ContentPlaceHolder1_btnReport").Click
Do Until Not IE.Busy And IE.readyState = 4
    DoEvents
Loop
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using queryselector to find the onclick event that corresponded to the start and end date calendar toggles.

```
Dim doc As HTMLDocument
'Click Calendar icon
Set doc = ie.document
doc.querySelector("img[onclick='ctl00xContentPlaceHolder1xtxtstartdateClass.toggleCalendarShow()']").Click
Call ie.document.parentWindow.execScript("ctl00xContentPlaceHolder1xtxtstartdateClass.selectDate ((12));", "JavaScript")

doc.querySelector("img[onclick='ctl00xContentPlaceHolder1xtxtenddateClass.toggleCalendarShow()']").Click
Call ie.document.parentWindow.execScript("ctl00xContentPlaceHolder1xtxtenddateClass.selectDate ((02));", "JavaScript")
```

I will get user input to choose the day of the month, and if needed to scroll through months I will do that by working out how many clicks that is from the current month. It seems clunky but probably I will be the only one using this anyway, and at least it should work.

Answer (score 0):

From the screenshot, we can see that the Date textbox using the `readonly` attribute, before using VBA script to find this element and write values in it, we need to remove the `readonly` attribute. Then, using `Application.SendKeys` method to send the value into the Date TextBox. More detail information, please refer to the following sample code:

```
    Set startDateText = IE.document.getElementbyId("startdate")

    'remove the readonly attribute.
    startDateText.removeAttribute ("readonly")
    startDateText.Focus

    'using sendkeys method to enter the date.         
    Application.SendKeys "10/21/2019", True

    'Waiting the date value enters (3 second) 
    Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:03"))

    Set endDateText = IE.document.getElementbyId("enddate")
    endDateText.Focus        
    Application.SendKeys "10/28/2019", True 
    Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:03"))

    IE.document.all("startdate").Click
```

The Html resource as below:

```
Start Date: <input type="text" id="startdate" name="startdate" value="" readOnly = "readonly" class="form-control" size="30">   
End Date: <input type="text" id="enddate" name="enddate" value="" class="form-control" size="30">
```

Comment: The start and end date boxes can't be typed into. I tried this solution and I got "Object variable or with block variable not set". I used the ID as what was shown in the attached screenshot.